# error HTTP failure during parsing URL when Handle Response create excel file

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 App Upload file. I make Angular App upload files

so first I choose a file then press the upload button

then I expect I get file Downloaded as Output but This not happen

the angular app did not return downloaded file so I have the issue on the response of angular and I need to fix it

I check repose of angular I get error HTTP failure during parsing link on line 115 as Image below.

line 115 Error angular on line post subscribe

```js
this.http.post('https://localhost:44396/api/ApprovalQuality/', formData).subscribe(
  (data) => {},
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  },
);
```

on response above it must return Excel file but it displays error

error HTTP failure during parsing URL  line 115 and not create excel file

Full Code

**component.html**

```html
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="uploadFile(files)">
  Upload File
</button>
```

**component.ts**

```js
fileToUpload: File = null;

handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
  this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
}
public uploadFile = (files) => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);

  this.http
    .post('https://localhost:44396/api/ApprovalQuality/', formData)

    .subscribe(
      (data) => {},
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    );
};
```

[image: reponse file not create excel file]

Comment: thank you for reply can you please write Response code complete after modification by code please

Comment: if possible can you show me answer by code

Comment: only if possible can you write sample code to your answer please I need to know where write response type text/plain and where set application/oct-stream and where write url.createobjecturl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reposeType is `text/plain`, it's must be set `application/octet-stream`. And then, you can use `blob` and `URL.createObjectURL` to download the excel file.

Comment: only if possible can you write sample code to your answer please I need to know where write response type text/plain and where set application/oct-stream and where write url.createobjecturl